# how do I convert a date int to datetime ( Getdate() ) in sql server?

Tags: datetime, integer

how do I convert or cast a date in integer like yyymmdd to a datetime format so that and picks today's date , getdate() ?

I have tried these:

> cast(DateIDas ,getdate()) 
>   cast(DateID,as datetime,getdate()

Comment: You have not accepted any answers for all your questions (which is already answered). It will lead people not to answer your questions, please work on that tooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 112)
```

with variable

```
DECLARE @myDate DATE= '10/15/2014'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @myDate, 112)
```

convert date(int) into datetime

```
DECLARE @myIntDate int= 20141015;
select MyDate = cast(cast(@myIntDate as char(8)) as datetime);
```

Comment: Where do I add the target variable in that? - After varchar?

Comment: No.. instead of getdate().. getdate() gives current date. Worked ?

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though. I had to rewrite it to this as my DateID variable is an integet:convert(int,convert(VARCHAR(10) ,DateID, 112)). The problem I am getting now is that I am getting some 2,000 rows less compared to manually typing in today's date. the date format of the integer is like this: 20141015. Do you have any suggestions for the above?

Comment: DECLARE @myIntDate int= 20141015;
select MyDate = cast(cast(@myIntDate as char(8)) as datetime);